# want to update record if exists and insert if not exists

Tags: vb.net

want to update record if exists and insert if not exists into vsolv_trn_tsalesregdump Is tsalesregdump_name is unique in table vsolv_trn_tsalesregdump

when i click check box that particular row should be check on other table and how to use it for loop in form loop i can use the "tsalesdump_date,tsalesdump_name,executivename_executive" this three if the value is same its go to update and otherwise its not to same its move on insert how can i write it can any 1help me

if i have use two table one temp and other 1 is orginal\   temp table =vsolv_tmp_tsalesdump   orginal table=vsolv_trn_tsalesregdump.

if already i hav save the data in orginal table,again if i hav assing data for temp table and view in radgrid if select and submit the button its go to check on orginal table if the value is already there its update it otherwise insert   how can use it

```
Protected Sub btn_Submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btn_Submit.Click
    lblerrmsg.Text = ""
    Dim chk As CheckBox
    Dim lbtn As LinkButton
    Dim Res As Long
    Dim lobjrow As DataRow
    Dim lObjErrTable As New DataTable
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim dtcarbooking As New DataTable
    Dim dtDumpBooking As New DataTable
    Dim lsRefid As String = String.Empty
    Dim dtdumpsample As New DataTable
    Dim name As String = String.Empty

    If Check_Validation() = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Gobjdbconn.OpenConn()

    lObjErrTable = Error_TabelFill()

    For i As Integer = 0 To GVUpload.Items.Count - 1
        chk = GVUpload.Items(i).FindControl("chkupload")
        If chk.Checked = True Then

                lsRefid = GVUpload.Items(i).GetDataKeyValue("tsalesdump_gid").ToString()


            MsSql = ""
            MsSql &= "Select tsalesdump_gid,tsalesdump_date,tsalesdump_name,executivename_executive,tsalesdump_vch_no,tsalesdump_debit,tsalesdump_credit"
            MsSql &= " from vsolv_tmp_tsalesdump as a"
            MsSql &= " left join vsolv_trn_executivename as b on a.tsalesdump_name = b.executivename_particulars"
            MsSql &= " where tsalesdump_gid = '" & lsRefid & "' and tsalesdump_isremoved = 'N'"
            dtDumpBooking = Gobjdbconn.GetDataTable(MsSql)


            MsSql = ""
            MsSql &= "Insert into vsolv_trn_tsalesregdump(tsalesregdump_date,tsalesregdump_name,tsalesregdump_executive,tsalesregdump_vch_no"
            MsSql &= " ,tsalesregdump_debit,tsalesregdump_credit,tsalesregdump_importby)"
            MsSql &= " Values ('" & Format(CDate(dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_date")), "yyyy-MMM-dd").ToString() & "'"
            MsSql &= ",'" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_name").ToString() & "'"
            MsSql &= ",'" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("executivename_executive").ToString() & "'"
            MsSql &= " ,'" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_vch_no").ToString() & "'"
            MsSql &= " ,'" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_debit").ToString() & "','" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_credit").ToString() & "','SIVA')"

            MnResult = Gobjdbconn.ExecuteNonQuerySQL(MsSql)

            If MnResult = 1 Then
                MsSql = ""
                MsSql &= " Delete from vsolv_tmp_tsalesdump where tsalesdump_gid = '" & lsRefid & "'"
                Gobjdbconn.ExecuteNonQuerySQL(MsSql)
            Else
                lobjrow = lObjErrTable.NewRow()
                a = a + 1
                lobjrow("Sno") = a
                lobjrow("Booking Ref No") = dtcarbooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesregdump_name").ToString
                lobjrow("Description") = "Duplicate Record"
                lObjErrTable.Rows.Add(lobjrow)
            End If

        End If
    Next


    POPSummary()

    If Not lObjErrTable Is Nothing Then
        If lObjErrTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Call Pop_Data(lObjErrTable)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: **Confused...** due to bad english..  Do you want to update record if exists and insert if not exists into `vsolv_trn_tsalesregdump`?     Is `tsalesregdump_name` is unique in table `vsolv_trn_tsalesregdump`?

Comment: yes  how can i use it

Comment: @BloodholderAnsih try with MERGE COMMAND

Comment: Have you found solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update record if already exists else insert in SQL then you can achieve by following: You need to change MsSql string for Insert command

```
MsSql = "" + _
"IF EXISTS(Select tsalesregdump_name From vsolv_trn_tsalesregdump Where tsalesregdump_name = '" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_name").ToString() & "') " + _
"BEGIN " + _
"   Update vsolv_trn_tsalesregdump " + _
"   Set tsalesregdump_date = '" & Format(CDate(dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_date")), "yyyy-MMM-dd").ToString() & "' " + _
"       ,tsalesregdump_executive = '" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("executivename_executive").ToString() & "' " + _
"       ,tsalesregdump_vch_no = '" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_vch_no").ToString() & "' " + _
"       ,tsalesregdump_debit = '" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_debit").ToString() & "' " + _
"       ,tsalesregdump_credit = '" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_credit").ToString() & "' " + _
"       ,tsalesregdump_importby = 'SIVA' " + _
"   Where tsalesregdump_name = '" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_name").ToString() & "' " + _
"END " + _
"ELSE " + _
"BEGIN " + _
"   Insert into vsolv_trn_tsalesregdump(tsalesregdump_date,tsalesregdump_name,tsalesregdump_executive,tsalesregdump_vch_no " + _
"       ,tsalesregdump_debit,tsalesregdump_credit,tsalesregdump_importby) " + _
"   Values ('" & Format(CDate(dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_date")), "yyyy-MMM-dd").ToString() & "' " + _
"   ,'" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_name").ToString() & "' " + _
"   ,'" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("executivename_executive").ToString() & "' " + _
"   ,'" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_vch_no").ToString() & "' " + _
"   ,'" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_debit").ToString() & "','" & dtDumpBooking.Rows(0).Item("tsalesdump_credit").ToString() & "','SIVA') " + _
"END "

MnResult = Gobjdbconn.ExecuteNonQuerySQL(MsSql)
```

I am assuming here that `tsalesregdump_name` is unique.

Comment: Thanks to share this code its working fine tnx ur help